# Sense hat install to non-Raspbian distro?

Tags: kali, sense-hat

Is it possible to install [the sense hat](https://www.raspberrypi.org/products/sense-hat/) on Kali linux (or other GNU/Linux distro)? Or is Raspbian necessary?

Comment: [Kali](https://unix.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/5360/why-is-kali-linux-so-hard-to-set-up-why-wont-people-help-me)

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

```
sudo apt-get update
sudo apt-get install sense-hat
sudo reboot
```

Or try building it from the source
https://github.com/RPi-Distro/python-sense-hat